# Examples of System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization Namespace Usage

Tags: .net, winforms, serialization, windows-forms-designer

I am looking for examples of implementation of following interfaces available in the namespace: [System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.design.serialization.aspx)

```
IDesignerLoaderService

IDesignerSerializationProvider

IDesignerSerializationService

IDesignerSerializationManager
```

Any link/code would be appreciated.